# How to visualize this binary file better?

Tags: unix, binary

I look at the source code of file and see

[image]

I run `file script` and see

```
 ELF 64-bit LSB executable, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), 
 for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
```

I recall that I have been able to read this binary as plain text sometimes and saw that it is filesystem dependent script. 
However, I forgot how I did it. 
The script is just splitting a file and just interested in what is the split pattern what it is using. 
However, with those `^@` signs it is difficult to make sense of it. 
However, there are rather much text which you can read.

How can you visualize such a binary file better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest to use the [strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strings_(Unix)) command:

```
strings script | less
```

Note that despite its name, `script` is not a script but a binary executable, as `file` shows.